# How to identify family of function from given property

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

A={$f:R\to R$}

with following properties

f has derivative of every order

$\forall x,y\in R$ $f(x+y)-f(y-x)=2xf'(y)$

then I have to find whole family

Till now I just able to show $f(x)-f(-x)/2x=2xf'(0)$

I wanted to solve this problem.

Please provide just hint..

Thanks in Advanced

Comment: Plug $y = x$ into the equation and use Taylor series ($f$ has a Taylor series since it's infinitely differentiable).

Comment: Sir I have  done that , I got f(y)=f(0)+yf'(y/2).

Comment: form here how I one identify given family is polynomial of degree less than 2